# 4 frames, refresh each one on random timer

Tags: javascript, html, random

This is what I have so far by using code I've found online. 
Two problems:

1. I can't figure out why the example page (google) doesn't load in the frames.
2. I hope I can get your input on a good random function to refresh at a random interval that is larger than X minutes but shorter than Y minutes.

```html
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Frames</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<FRAMESET ROWS="50%, *" COLS="*, 50%">
     <FRAME name="frame1" SRC="http://www.google.com">
     <FRAME name="frame2" SRC="http://www.google.com">
     <FRAME name="frame3" SRC="http://www.google.com">
     <FRAME name="frame4" SRC="http://www.google.com">
</FRAMESET>

<script type="text/javascript">
 window.setTimeout("window.frames['frame1'].reload()", 60000);
</script>


</HTML>
```

Comment: looks like `frameset` is not supported anymore in HTML5. I recommand you to choose something else.

Comment: Agree with @Seblor. An alternative way could be to change `<frameset>` to `<div>`, then change `<frame>` to `<iframe>`. But then comes the answer to your 1st question: you can't get your google page loaded because of `Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://www.google.fr/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=C9DgVtPPO5Pu8wfS5IrIDQ&gws_rd=ssl does not permit cross-origin framing.`

Comment: Thank you. I tried DIV and IFRAME by replacing the other wods but it resulted in just one box in the top left; maybe they use a different syntax. In the mean time i found Refresh Monkey extension for chrome, but i thought i could make some simple code instead of having 4 browsers open at the same time. I am not a programmer in any way but i know the basics. What other way do you suggest to refresh a certain page at a random interval.